# Unable to set canonical for Magento 2 homepage

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have added below code to my homepage by going to Content->Pages-> in layout xml under design. But doesn't seem to reflect in the frontend. I am using Magento 2.2.0 with Ultimo Theme

```
    <reference name="head">
  <action method="addLinkRel">
    <rel>canonical</rel>
    <href>https://www.example.com</href>
  </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a canonical link to homepage with existing theme Ultimo:

> 1. app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link rel="canonical" src="https://www.example.com" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

OR

You can try following code with new module:

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link rel="canonical" src="https://www.example.com" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 4):

`<link>` elements are not allowed in the homepage Layout Update XML.

You can add a canonical link to your homepage by creating or editing `cms_index_index.xml` in

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Cms/layout/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link rel="canonical" src="http://domain.com" src_type="url" />
    </head> 
</page>
```

Clear static files and cache and you're done.

Comment: How to add to search result page?

Comment: Add the same code to `catalogsearch_result_index.xml` in `app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/`

Answer (score -3):

**Try this below code.**
Please change the 'someurl' as per your requirements. And place it in  layout section in admin.

```
  <link rel="canonical" src="someurl" src_type="url"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It isn't work for me.